# Npm run build/deploy does not works and throw "failed to compile errors"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I tried to run npm run deploy/ build but it doesn't work and throws this error in the terminal. I am a beginner to git and github and I want to upload my changes that I made in my latest commit to my github pages but it no matter how many time I tried, it always says fails to compile

the error message in terminal:

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

static/css/main.9391ac5d.css from Css Minimizer plugin
Error: Unexpected '/'. Escaping special characters with \ may help.

Comment: Looking at the error message, there seems to be an unexpected "/" in your css. So, maybe check your css for any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some extra characters which were added by mistake while commenting few things
Check for any extra / or * in your css files